# kdenlive unable to show corectly or open folders or files with Unicode names (Ex: Arabic)

Tags: unity, gnome, unicode, kdenlive, arabic

I was working on `kdenlive` correctly with out any problem in Ubuntu 13.04 x32.

I use Ubuntu13.04 x64 Unity and installed Kdenlive form software center. I can't open clip that has an Arabic name or in a folder with Arabic name. When I write a title clip in Arabic and render a video .. I find nothing.

I have Ubuntu 13.04 x64 and kdenlive 0.9.6

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the name of the folder or file to "Test", OR "إختبار" :)

Comment: he tried this my bro but the second big problem is he can't write arabic in title clip and in program too // I think in another temp solution about write arabic that is he can write what he need in other editing photos like gimp or pinta and save this and import it in kdenlive for his clip as picture

Comment: @Mahmoud20070, If you still facing this problem. Could you please try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an old bug was in KDE. It has been already fixed. So I give a try in Gnome (Ubuntu 14.04), yep same problem scrambled ASCII letters instead of Arabic ones. Then I installed KDE Plasma desktop, weird `kdenlive` works as it should (Arabic folders names readable, opened and I even added Arabic named clip). Back to Gnome, kdenlive still as it was, unreadable Arabic folder names and could not be opened.

What works for me, Run:

```
kdeinit4
```

Then launch `kdenlive` again.

(I don't know if there any specific config which are loaded by `kdeinit4`. It comes with `kdelibs-bin` no need to install KDE)

Comment: i use

 [link](kdeinit4) 

and i coud now  open folders an clips thar are written in arabic but i still face a proplem   

When I write a title clip in Arabic and render a video .. I find nothing.

Comment: @ahmedakef, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, KDE Dev 4.13.0, Kdenlive 0.9.6. Arabic is rendered well, Have tried other fonts.